# Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, конструктор, инициализация

У меня есть конструктор класса примерно вот такого вида:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, ..., an):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a2 = a2
        ...
        self.an = an
    ...
```

Можно ли как-то упростить процесс инициализации, а то писать n повторяющихся строчек совсем не интересно.

**UPD.** Дополню вопрос:

1. Как быть в случае, когда присутствуют значения по умолчанию?

   ```
   class B:
       def __init__(self, b1=b1_0, b2=b2_0, ..., bn=bn_0):
           self.b1 = b1
           self.b2 = b2
           ...
           self.bn = bn
       ...
   ```
2. Возможно ответ последует из п.1, но всё равно задам ещё один вопрос: Что делать, если для каких-то аргументов есть значение по умолчанию, а для каких-то нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если неизменяемый объект хотите создать, представляющий запись с полями,
 можно использовать [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

A = namedtuple("A", "a1 a2    an")
A.__new__.__defaults__ = (0,) * 3  # set default values
print(A(1, 2))
# -> A(a1=1, a2=2, an=0)
```

Для изменяемых объектов, можно использовать [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

print(SimpleNamespace(a1=1, a2=2, an=3))
# -> namespace(a1=1, a2=2, an=3)
```

`SimpleNamespace` это простая альтернатива конструкции: `class NS: pass`, которая за вас `__init__`, `__repr__`, `__eq__` методы определяет.

Чтобы указать типы, в неизменяемом случае, можно использовать [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class B(NamedTuple):
    b1: str = '0'
    b2: int = 1

print(B())      # -> B(b1='0', b2=1)
print(B(b2=3))  # -> B(b1='0', b2=3)
```

[PEP 557 -- Data Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#abstract) (Python 3.7+) хочет ввести классы данных для случая «изменяемые namedtuple со значениями по умолчанию».  Для предыдущих версий Питона, можно использовать неинтегрированную в стандартную библиотеку реализацию из [dataclasses пакета](https://github.com/ericvsmith/dataclasses):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass  # $ pip install dataclasses

@dataclass
class B:
    b1: str = '0'
    b2: int = 1

print(B())  # -> B(b1='0',b2=1)
b = B(b2=2)
print(b)    # -> B(b1='0',b2=2)
b.b1 = '1'
print(b)    # -> B(b1='1',b2=2)
```

В более общем случае, [можно воспользоваться `attrs` пакетом](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs), который множество дополнительной функциональности предоставляет. См. ещё примеры в ответе на похожий вопрос: [Как создать коллекцию объектов пользовательского класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653719/23044)

Comment: PEP 557 буквально на днях утвердили: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151034.html

Answer (score 12):

Тогда уж так:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

`kwargs` - это словарь аргументов (пары "имя": значение).

Вариант со значениями по-умолчанию:

```
class A:
     __defaults = dict(b1=1, b2='2', foo='bar')

     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         self.__dict__.update(self.__defaults)
         self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

Первоначально класс инициализируется значениями по-умолчанию (`__defaults`), а потом значениями из `kwargs`. Если в `kwargs` есть аргументы, присутствующие в `__defaults`, то новые значения (из `kwargs`) заменят старые (из `__defaults`).

---

Можно использовать функцию [`store_attr`](https://fastcore.fast.ai/basics.html#store_attr) из библиотеки [`fastcore`](https://pypi.org/project/fastcore/), она берет все параметры метода и записывает их значения в атрибуты объекта с теми же именами (если какой-то параметр не нужно прописывать в атрибуты, это можно настроить, см. документацию).

```
from fastcore.utils import store_attr


class B:
    def __init__(self, a, b1=1, b2=2, b3=333):
        store_attr()
    
    def update(self, a, b1, b2, b3):
        store_attr()


b = B(a='aaa')
print(b.a, b.b1, b.b2, b.b3)

b.update('bbb', 3, 2, 1)
print(b.a, b.b1, b.b2, b.b3)
```

Answer (score 5):

Мне больше нравится следующий метод:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, ..., an):
        self.__dict__.update({k: v for k, v in locals().items() if k != 'self'})
```

Немного теории:

- `__dict__` хранит определенные пользователем атрибуты объекта, в нашем случае мы ручками добавляем в него новые значения, он представляет из себя словарь, где ключ это имя атрибута, а значение - значение соответствующего атрибута
- `locals()` возвращает локальные переменные, в нашем случае - аргументы `__init__`
- `self` фильтруем, его нам задавать не нужно

Answer (score 4):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, ..., an):
        for i in self.__init__.__code__.co_varnames[1:-1]:
            exec('self.{0} = {0}'.format(i))
```

Идея в чем: получаем список всех аргументов `__init__`, потом в цикле, исключая `self`, присваиваем каждый аргумент атрибуту объекта с таким же названием.