# Python: Произвольное количество аргументов в конструкторе класса

Tags: python, классы, конструктор

Долго искал, как передать в `__init__` произвольное кол-во аргументов. Вот [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187082/how-can-you-set-class-attributes-from-variable-arguments-kwargs-in-python/39158682#39158682) нашел:

```
class Thing:
'''a class with a constructor (or other function) 
   that takes a variable number of arguments and then 
   sets them as class attributes conditionally.
'''
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

door = Thing(size='180x70', color='red chestnut', material='oak')
print(door.size, door.color, door.material, sep = ', ')

house = Thing(height='23 m', doors=6, rooms=4, material='break') #180x70, red chestnut, oak
print(house.height, house.doors, house.rooms, house.material, sep=', ') #23 m, 6, 4, break
```

Уверен, есть решение короче раза в 2, но не могу найти.

Comment: Посмотрите ответы в этом вопросе: [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495719/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python?rq=1)

Comment: В чём состоит вопрос?

Comment: вопрос такой:
есть проблема - как передать в __инит__ произвольное количество аргументов для каждого экземпляра класса

есть приведенное мной решение проблемы - 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            for key, value in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, key, value)

вопрос - так правильно делать или есть "более лудший" метод?

Comment: К вопросу по ссылке, которую вы указали, есть [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8187408/4752653) с использованием `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`. Проще уже некуда.

Comment: Более лучшим методом было бы не использовать один класс для столь разнородных сущностей, а отнаследовать от него отдельный класс для дверей, отдельный класс для домов и т.п. Но если уж это невозможно, то пользуйтесь тем методом, который вы нашли. Глупо искать более красивую реализацию для изначально неправильных решений проектирования.

Comment: Что лучше, зависит от конкретного случая: в одном случае `types.SimpleNamespace` подойдёт, в другом `collections.namedtuple`, в третьем вообще словарь (dict, OrderedDict) как есть использовать, есть ещё сторонние библиотеки, которые свои разновидности классов предоставляют, позволяя упростить их создание, например `@case` классы из MacroPy или `@attr.attributes`,  и вариант из вопроса также может быть применим в некоторых случаях. Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Thing(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]
```

или

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```