# Различия между двумя способами создания объектов класса

Tags: python, ооп, python-3.x, классы

Есть много людей, которых нужно вручную внести в код. Данные об этих людях никогда не будут изменяться, их нужно будет только иногда запрашивать. В чем разница между двумя кодами ниже? Какой лучше вариант или как лучше решить такую задачку?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, sex, numbers):
        self.sex = sex
        self.numbers = numbers
andrew = Person("Male", ("8 800 555 35 35", "8 900 800 70 60"))
julia = Person("Female", ("8 999 888 77 66", "8 123 456 78 90"))
```

Или:

```
class Person:
    pass

andrew = Person()
andrew.sex = "Male"
andrew.numbers = ("8 800 555 35 35", "8 900 800 70 60")

julia = Person()
julia.sex = "Female"
julia.numbers = ("8 999 888 77 66", "8 123 456 78 90")
```

Comment: *"Данные об этих людях никогда не будут изменяться"*--на практике, вероятность того, что захочется добавить дополнительную колонку в данные высока.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495719/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Есть много людей, которых нужно вручную внести в код.

Используйте формат, который наиболее удобен человеку, который вводит данные, например, простой текстовый файл в csv формате:

```
M, 8 800 555 35 35, 89008007060
F, 8 999 888 77 66, 8 123 456 78 90
```

или создайте небольшой [UI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) для удобства (текстовый или GUI или используйте существующий интерфейс такой как Excel), чтобы налету корректность данных проверять (что пол содержит только два значения (genderqueer не существует), номера содержат цифры итд) и записывайте в базу данных такую как sqlite напрямую (при чтении позже [можно `row_factory` использовать, чтобы объекты нужного типа получить](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) или использовать тип, предоставляемый [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) такой как в [`sqlalchemy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)).

> Данные об этих людях никогда не будут изменяться

В таких случаях [удобно `collections.namedtuple` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), если тип объекта руками задаётся:

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'sex numbers')

andrew = Person("Male", ("8 800 555 35 35", "8 900 800 70 60"))
julia = Person("Female", ("8 999 888 77 66", "8 123 456 78 90"))
```

В этом случае нельзя изменять доступные атрибуты, например, как `julia.age = 10` так и `julia.numbers = ()` запрещено.

Если вы хотите изменять существующие атрибуты, добавлять новые, то чтобы создать подобные объекты налету (имена атрибутов и данные задаются динамически во время исполнения и могут быть позже изменены), [можно `types.SimpleNamespace` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace). 
Связанный вопрос: [Python: create object and add attributes to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2827623/4279).

> В чем разница между двумя кодами ниже?

Обычно все атрибуты объекта должны быть заданы в `__init__`—не следует определять дополнительные атрибуты вне `__init__` без особых на то оснований. Второй пример кода в вопросе ближе к `SimpleNamespace` (без некоторых удобных методов), первый пример кода в вопросе ближе к namedtuple (без гарантий неизменности).

Comment: Спасибо! Это приемлемо, много раз использовать SimpleNamespace вот так? Людей ведь будет много.

    from types import SimpleNamespace
    andrew = SimpleNamespace(sex="Male", number="12345")
    julia = SimpleNamespace(sex="Female", number="67890")

Comment: @NickCaulfield: как я предложил, используйте csv и namedtuple в вашем случае, например, чтобы прочитать csv файл и сохранить каждого человека как namedtuple, показанную выше: `people = [Person(["Male", "Female"][sex=="M"], tuple(numbers)) for sex, *numbers in csv.reader(open("people.csv"))]`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. И всё же, хотелось бы узнать, что насчет моего вопроса? Будет ли всё настолько плохо, если я сделаю это с помощью SimpleNamespace?

Comment: @NickCaulfield можно гвозди отвёрткой вбивать, но зачем. Разные инструменты для разных задач могут лучше подходить. В сторону: ошибка в моём комментарии—нужно `==` на `!=` заменить.

Answer (score 5):

Создавать классы и экземпляры этих классов для хранения данных, я считаю, оверхед. Проще для использования как в самом питоне, так и вообще:

```
SEX_MALE = 'Male'
SEX_FEMALE = 'Female'

andrew = {'sex': SEX_MALE, 'numbers': ('123 123 123', '345 345 345')}
julia =  {'sex': SEX_FEMALE, 'numbers': ('321 312 312', '654 654 645')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Брать объект от пустого класса и уже для конкретного объекта формировать структуру - очень плохой вариант.
Даже если конкретно для вашего случая разницы никакой не будет, то при попытке расширять или менять код вы будете натыкаться на огромное количество заботливо разложенных граблей.

Но даже если вы решите, что дорабатывать скрипт в будущем не понадобиться, он будет нужен только под текущую задачу, второй вариант чреват большой вероятностью ошибок. Ну и вообще - нужно приучать себя всегда использовать правильные решения.

Ну и лучше данные для инициализации всех этих людей не хардкодить в скрипте, а сохранить в отдельный файл, и инициализировать экземпляры класса в цикле, читая данные из файла.

Comment: Вообще код на питоне - как раз отдельный текстовый файл. Очень удобно хранить данные именно в формате файла `python`. Не случайно Django хранит конфигурацию именно в `settings.py`.

Comment: @Nikmoon и больше ничего кроме конфигурации и миграций :)

Comment: @Nikmoon, всё-таки для хранения большого числа записей с заданным набором полей лучше использовать другие форматы файлов - например, CSV