# Как создать коллекцию объектов пользовательского класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Недавно мне попался вопрос по `C#`, где парень спрашивал как сохранить данные класса.

У него был такой класс:

```cs
class Passenger
{
    public string name;
    public string surname;
    public string country;
    public int age;
    public Passenger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Give a name to your passenger");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Give a surname to your passenger");
        surname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Where is " + name + " from?");
        country = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("How old is " + name + " ?");
        age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }
```

И сохранить коллекции в его случае можно с помощью `List<Passenger> passengers = new List<Passenger>()`

Но как сохранить коллекцию такого класса в `Python`? Я полагаю, что нужно воспользоваться импортом какой-то специфической библиотеки типа:

```
from collections import *
```

Comment: @gil9red спасибо за правку косяка

Comment: Не надо никаких специфических библиотек, стандартный список может хранить объекты любых классов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, я уже потестил. Что теперь делать? Удалять вопрос?

Comment: Отметьте ответ gil9red решением.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev русское коммьюнити бессмысленное и беспощадное. Я задал вопрос, меня заминусовали, я сам нашёл ответ на свой вопрос, пришёл парень с репой побольше, ответил чуть более подробно, ему дали плюс, и теперь от меня требуют, чтобы я отметил его ответ, как решение

Comment: Я не требую. Вы спросили, я ответил.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В питоне нет шаблонов (привет с++) или генериков (привет java), просто добавляйте в нужную коллекцию, например создаем миникласс:

```
class Passenger:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, country, age):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.country = country
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Passenger (name={}, age={})>'.format(self.name, self.age)

    
passenger = Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 'Россия', 16)
print(passenger)  # <Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>

clones = list()
clones.append(passenger)
print(clones)  # [<Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>]

for i in range(5):
    passenger = Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 'Россия', 16 + i)
    clones.append(passenger)

print(clones)  # [<Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=17)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=18)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=19)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=20)>]

print(clones[0])  # <Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>
print(clones[3])  # <Passenger (name=Иван, age=18)>
print(clones[-1])  # <Passenger (name=Иван, age=20)>
print()
print(clones[:3])  # [<Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=16)>, <Passenger (name=Иван, age=17)>]
```

---

**PS.**

Класс с встроенным конструктором, проверкой полей и текстовым представлением можно создать через декоратор `dataclass`

Очень удобно:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Passenger:
    name: str
    name: str
    surname: str
    country: str
    age: int

passenger = Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 'Россия', 16)
print(passenger)
# Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', country='Россия', age=16)
```

Comment: [Нет необходимости свой класс писать в таких простых случаях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653719/23044)

Comment: @jfs, согласен, но если следовать примеру то до конца :)

Answer (score 8):

> Как создать коллекцию коллекций

Стандартные контейнеры  в Питоне (такие как list, tuple) способны хранить данные любого типа. К примеру, чтобы создать список списков `NxN`:

```
matrix = [[0]*N for _ in range(N)]
```

Что для `N=5` даёт:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

---

Для простых объектов, которые являются просто набором атрибутов нет необходимости свои классы писать всё время, [можно `collections.namedtuple` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

Passenger = namedtuple("Passenger", "name surname age country")

passenger = Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 16, 'Россия')
print(passenger)
# -> Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=16, country='Россия')
```

Чтобы список получить:

```
clones = [Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 16 + years, 'Россия')
          for years in range(5)]
print(clones)
```

Вывод:

```
[Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=16, country='Россия'), 
 Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=17, country='Россия'), 
 Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=18, country='Россия'), 
 Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=19, country='Россия'), 
 Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=20, country='Россия')]
```

При желании, [можно типы указать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Passenger(NamedTuple):
    """Represents a passenger."""
    name: str
    surname: str
    age: int
    country: str = 'Россия'

print(Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 16))
# -> Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=16, country='Россия')
```

Если нужны изменяемые поля, то [есть `types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

passenger = SimpleNamespace(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=16, country='Россия')
passenger.age += 1  # happy birthday  
print(passenger)
# -> namespace(age=17, country='Россия', name='Иван', surname='Иванов')
```

В более сложных случаях [можно `attrs` пакет попробовать](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import attr  # $ pip install attrs

Passenger = attr.make_class("Passenger", ["name", "surname", "age", "country"])

passenger = Passenger('Иван', 'Иванов', 16, 'Россия')
passenger.age += 1
print(passenger)
print(attr.astuple(passenger))
print(attr.asdict(passenger))
```

Результат:

```
Passenger(name='Иван', surname='Иванов', age=17, country='Россия')
('Иван', 'Иванов', 17, 'Россия')
{'name': 'Иван', 'surname': 'Иванов', 'age': 17, 'country': 'Россия'}
```

Все эти классы позволяют быстро создать свой класс без необходимости определять свои `__init__`,  `__repr__`, `__eq__` методы. attrs модуль дополнительно предоставляет возможность задавать значения по умолчанию, определять автоматические преобразования, проверять значения по произвольным критериям и другое. [Примеры](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html).

Comment: Сложный выбор чей ответ лучше

Comment: @KitScribe, понятно же, чем проще, тем лучше (KISS-принцип)

Answer (score 4):

Как оказалось, никакие специальные библиотеки не нужны (по крайней мере не обязательны)

```
class Passenger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = input('Give a name to your passenger: ')
        self.surname = input('Give a second name to your passenger: ')
        self.country = input('Where is ' + self.name + ' '+ self.surname + ' from? ')
        self.age = int(input('How old is ' + self.name + ' '+ self.surname + ' ? '))

passengers = []

for x in range(3):
    passenger = Passenger()
    passengers.append(passenger)

for passenger in passengers:
    print(passenger) # вывод будет примерно таким <__main__.Passenger object at 0x7f4b945992b0>
    print(passenger.name, passenger.surname)
```