# Сумма параметров объектов

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

per1 = Person(20)
per2 = Person(30)

l = [per1, per2]
print(sum([getattr(x, 'age') for x in l]))
```

Допустим есть класс Person, параметр age и список из нескольких объектов. Как красивее и правильнее вычислить сумму age всех объектов? Мне на ум приходит

```
print(sum([getattr(x, 'age') for x in l]))
```

но может есть что-то красивее и проще?
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы можете писать: `x.age` вместо `getattr(x, 'age')`

Comment: Как вариант создайте метод который будет вам выводить сумму.

Comment: В сторону: [для простых объектов не обязательно свой класс писать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/653719/23044)

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про namedtuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы не обращаться напрямую к `Person.age`?

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

per1 = Person(20)
per2 = Person(30)

l = [per1, per2]
print(sum([x.age for x in l]))
```

Comment: Список здесь не обязательно создавать. Также, в общем случае,  `l` имя лучше избегать: `print(sum(p.age for p in persons))`

Comment: Точно! Что-то я перемудрил, спасибо.

Comment: `print(sum(p.age for p in persons))` а вот это не очень понял, что за persons?

Comment: @Gleb вместо `l` имени: `persons = [Person(20), Person(30)]`

Comment: Понял, спасибо )