# конструктор класса наследник в python 2

Tags: python, конструктор

Есть 2 класса: родитель и потомок.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, params1):
        self.params1 = params1
        #ещё куча опций и т.д.

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.paramsB1 = None
        pass
```

Как правильно записать **init** класса B, чтобы было возможно следующее:

```
a1 = A("10")
b1 = B(a1)
# при создании объекта класса B, данные объекта a1 копировались в объект b1.
# то есть b1.params1 стала равна "10"
# и есть ли возможность в питоне создавать несколько конструкторов класса?
# т.е.
# b1 = B(a1)  или 
# B("10") и в данном случае выполняется A.__init__(self, "10") в конструторе класса B
```

Comment: Посмотрите метод `super().__init__()`, такая конструкция должна вызвать конструктор предка

Comment: @gil9red ему нужен конструктор, принимающий экземпляр класса предка.

Comment: Зачем тут наследование? 1. Опишите два класса независимые друг от друга. 2. Создайте объект класса A. 3. Создайте класс B передайте в качестве параметра объект класса A.

Comment: @DmitryErohin, это простое решение, которое в принципе предлагает отказаться от наследования. Это просто пример. Но если классы имеют еще во многом и одинаковый функционал, многие одинаковые методы. Я и спрашиваю, можно ли именно унаследоваться?

Comment: @chromenoge, унаследоваться можно только от класса, а не от конкретного экземпляра. Если вам нужно копировать аттрибуты конкретного экземпляра - то это просто никак не связано с наследованием.

Comment: @Александр, не могу точно донести свою мысль. Я и спрашиваю как сделать конструктор, принимающий на вход объект своего родителя. Мне нужен override или какое то другое аналогичное решение. Но пока нашел только [вот такое решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495719/Можно-ли-как-нибудь-упростить-инициализацию-классов-на-python?rq=1)

Comment: @Александр, мне нужно чтобы в конструкторе класса В вызвался __конструктор копирования__ класса А.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, теперь я понял, о чём вы спрашиваете.

Чтобы скопировать все аттрибуты одного объекта в соответствующие аттрибуты другого, можно использовать `obj1.__dict__ = obj2.__dict__.copy()`

Два варианта метода инициализации в одном классе создать нельзя, но можно в одном методе реализовать разные варианты инициализации в зависимости от переданных параметров.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, params1):
        self.params1 = params1


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, A):
            self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__.copy()
        elif isinstance(obj, int):
            super(B, self).__init__(obj)
        else:
            raise Exception('Wrong arguments!')


a = A(1)
print(a.params1)

b = B(4)
print(b.params1)

b = B(a)
print(b.params1)
```

Если количество входных параметров может отличаться в разных случаях - гуглите *args и **kwargs.

Comment: правильнее всё-таки наверное будет не `self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__`, а self.__dict__.update(obj.__dict__). Разве так атрибуты скопируются? А не произойдёт присвоение указателей?

Comment: Проверил локально, изменеяя объект класса А, изменяется и объект класса В, при `self.__dict__ = obj.__dict__`.

Comment: При В(4) ложится с ошибкой: super().__init__(obj) TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @chromenoge, у вас вторая версия питона? Если да, то во второй super() немножко сложнее делается, сейчас я поправлю свой код.

Comment: Я решил проблему так. `A.__init__(self, obj)`. Да 2 версия.В названии темы указал.

Comment: @chromenoge, я поменял код в ответе под вторую версию питона.

Comment: @chromenoge, да, для простых случаев можно явно прописать родительский класс, без использования super(). Но в реальном коде, где может быть три и более уровня наследования и код периодически дорабатывается разными людьми - без super() уже сложновато.

Comment: По поводу дикта - да, вы правы, нужно использовать либо `update`, либо `copy`, это я стормозил. Я поправил мой код на вариант с 'copy'.

Comment: Пример чего именно?

Answer (score 1):

[`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)

```
import functools

def check_arg_type(func):
    d = functools.singledispatch(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        arg = args[1]
        return d.dispatch(arg.__class__)(*args, **kwargs)
    wrap.register = d.register
    return wrap

class A:
    def __init__(self, params1):
        self.params1 = params1

class B(object):
    @check_arg_type
    def __init__(self, arg):
        print('__init__ :', arg)
        self.s = arg

    @__init__.register(A)
    def _(self, arg):
        print('object :', arg)
        self.__dict__.update(arg.__dict__)

    @__init__.register(int)
    def _(self, arg):
        print('int :', arg)
        self.num = arg + 100

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = A('a1')
    b1 = B(obj)
    b2 = B(2)
    b3 = B('s3')
    print('Res:', b1.params1, b2.num, b3.s)  # a1 102 s3
```

out:

```
object : <__main__.A object at 0x0379BB90>
int : 2
__init__ : s3
Res: a1 102 s3
```