# Как в Python 3 проинициализировать существующий класс в 1 строке свойствами вне конструктора, подобно c#?

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x

В c# есть очень полезная конструкция. Если мне нужно создать экземпляр класса, а свойств, которые надо задать нет в конструкторе, то это можно делать в одной строке таким образом

```
var mc = new MyClass() { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "qwe" };
```

А можно подобное сделать в питоне?

Вообще требуется собрать список

```
list = [MyClass(el) for el in otherList]
```

Вот только проблема в том, что в конструктор MyClass ничего нельзя передать. Как мне в таком случае создать экземпляр и задать 1 или несколько свойств в одной строке?

**UPD:**

Вопрос похож на предыдущий, но вот те ответы меня не устраивают. Возможно, это потому что сам вопрос там был задан с меньшей конкретикой.

**UPD2:**

Ах да, вопрос все же отличается. Там человек спрашивает как повесить на автомат функцию инициализации класса, а я спрашиваю как использовать готовый класс, при этом ни намека на автоматику. В общем, советую внимательно вчитаться в оба вопроса, тогда все станет понятно

Comment: если новый класс с заданными свойствами хотите создать быстро, то см [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495719/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такого синтаксиса нет.

---

Но можно создать функцию хелпер:

```
def post_init(obj, **kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(obj, key, value)
    return obj
```

И юзать её:

```
l = [post_init(MyClass(), el=el) for el in otherList]
```

---

А можно подменить __init__(вообще вариант не оч, но тоже можно):

```
def replace_init(cls):
    cls__init__ = cls.__init__
    def my_init(self, el=None):
        cls__init__(self)
        self.el = el

    cls.__init__ = my_init

replace_init(MyCLass)
```

И юзать такой класс:

```
l = [MyClass(el) for el in otherList]
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что такое **kwargs? Где про это можно почитать?

Comment: @iRumba , вот хороший ответ  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651/Что-значит-звёздочка-и-двойная-звёздочка-в-Питоне

Comment: Как вариант еще можно отнаследоваться от исходного класса, и в `__init__` добавить инициализацию нужных параметров.

Comment: setattr жесть...инит лучше

Comment: @eri, не сказал бы перезапись инита чужого класса лучше, чем функция-хелпер.

Comment: а как же инкапсуляция, наследование, полиморфизм?

Comment: @eri ну так я и говорю, что можно отнаследоваться, и поменять инит как нужно, но не патчить его в исходном классе.