# Найти минимальное значение из словаря, упорядоченное по значению атрибута

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, словари

Пытаюсь отсортировать словарь объектов используя lambda функцию:

```
class A:
  x = 0
  y = 0
  id = 0

first = A()
second = A()
first.id = 1
first.x = 10
first.y = 20
second.id = 2
second.x = 15
second.y = 5


test = {first.id: first, second.id: second}

print(min(test, key=lambda unit: unit.x))
```

Интерпретатор говорит мне об отсутствии атрибута. Что необходимо тут исправить?

Comment: Словарь — итератор (точнее, он даёт итератор через метод `__iter__`), возвращающий в цикле ключи. `unit` в лямбде — это числа `1` и `2`

Comment: Кроме того, словари - это неупорядоченные коллекции, их невозможно отсортировать.

Comment: Т.е. необходимо написать test[unit].x ?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev но минимальный `x` найти всё же можно

Comment: @user269134 как вариант. Но, думаю, у питоноспецов могут найтись варианты покрасивее

Comment: уточните вопрос  -  по какому значению надо отсортировать?

Comment: В сторону: можно упростить инициализацию переменных: [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495719/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас есть словарь `test`, то `min(test)` найдет минимальный *ключ*. Если вы хотите найти минимальное *значение*, то следует использовать: `min(test.values())`.

Чтобы найти *значение* с минимальный атрибутом `x`:

```
min(test.values(), key=lambda unit: unit.x)
```

Вместо `lambda`, можно использовать [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter), чтобы сравнить значения атрибута `x`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

min(test.values(), key=attrgetter('x'))
```

Чтобы сравнить объекты сперва по значению атрибута `x`, а затем по значению атрибута `y`:

```
min(test.values(), key=attrgetter('x', 'y'))
```

Чтобы найти *ключ* в словаре, который соответствует значению с минимальным `x` атрибутом:

```
min(test, key=lambda unit: test[unit].x)
```

Answer (score 0):

если вы хотите отсортировать по возрастанию ключей, то надо в вашем примере писать

```
print(min(test, key=lambda unit: unit))
```

если вы хотите сортировать по значению объектов, то надо добавить метод __lt__ в Класс и писать

```
  print(min(test, key=lambda unit: test[unit]))
```

если вы хотите сортировать по A.y  -  вам нужно изменить словарь или в примере писать

```
print(min(test, key=lambda unit: test[unit].y))
```

ну и использовать

```
sorted()   вместо min()
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавляю примеры получения минимального и максимального элемента, и сортировки у пользовательского объекта по заданным критериям:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.id = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<A(id={}, x={}, y={})>'.format(self.id, self.x, self.y)


first = A()
first.id = 1
first.x = 10
first.y = 20

second = A()
second.id = 2
second.x = 15
second.y = 5

test = {first.id: first, second.id: second}
print(test)  # {1: <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>, 2: <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>}

print(min(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].x))  # (1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>)
print(max(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].x))  # (2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>)

# Сортировка
print(sorted(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].id))  # [(1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>), (2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>)]
print(sorted(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].id, reverse=True))  # [(2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>), (1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>)]
print()

print(sorted(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].x))  # [(1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>), (2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>)]
print(sorted(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].x, reverse=True))  # [(2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>), (1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>)]
print()

print(sorted(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].y))  # [(2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>), (1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>)]
print(sorted(test.items(), key=lambda unit: unit[1].y, reverse=True))  # [(1, <A(id=1, x=10, y=20)>), (2, <A(id=2, x=15, y=5)>)]
```

---

UPD. Добавил конструктор `__init__` и перенес свойства класса в свойства объекта

Comment: Как это у вас код без `__init__` работает?

Comment: @AndrioSkur, `__init__` необязательный, и если не указывать свой, то вызовится родительский

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, oid):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.oid = oid

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A(x={}, y={}, oid={})'.format(self.x, self.y, self.oid)


first = A(x=10, y=20, oid=1)
second = A(x=15, y=5, oid=2)
test = {first.oid: first, second.oid: second}

print(min(test.values(), key=lambda unit: unit.x))
```