# Как упорядочить словарь?

Tags: python, list, словари

Имеется вот такого рода дикт

```
cars = {'id': 82, 'name': '6 (E63, E64)', 'car_brand_id': 83, 'car_brand_name': 'BMW'}, {'id': 83, 'name': '7 (E38)', 'car_brand_id': 83, 'car_brand_name': 'BMW'}, {'id': 84, 'name': '7 (E65, E66)', 'car_brand_id': 83, 'car_brand_name': 'BMW'}, {'id': 85, 'name': '7 (F01, F02, F03, F04)', 'car_brand_id': 83, 'car_brand_name': 'BMW'}, {'id': 86, 'name': '8 (E31)', 'car_brand_id': 83, 'car_brand_name': 'BMW'}

a = []

for i in cars:
    a.append([a for a in i.values()])

for car in a:
    # в user.model_auto лежит обычное произвольное строковое название машины
    if user.model_auto.lower() in car[0].lower():
```

Собственно после этого и возникают ошибки. Т.к словарь каждый раз передается иначе. И вместо `car[0]`, где должно быть имя - передается `id` или еще чего.

Могу ли я как-то упорядочить и сделать всегда 1 вывод?

Comment: Вам вывод куда нужен? Можно например использовать форматирование строк, `D = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}` `print("key1: {0[key1]:}\nkey2: {0[key2]:}".format(D))`

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам действительно нужно выгружать значения в список, а потом обращаться к ним по индексу? Проще же оставить словарь и обращаться по ключу: `car['name'].lower()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словарь - это неупорядоченная коллекция. Если нужен порядок следования элементов, используйте [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Ещё больше в вашем случае подойдёт [именованный кортеж](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
Brand = namedtuple('Brand', ['id', 'name'])
Car = namedtuple('Car', ['id', 'name', 'brand'])

bmw_brand = Brand(83, 'BMW')
cars = [
    Car(82, '6 (E63, E64)', bmw_brand),
    Car(83, '7 (E38)', bmw_brand),
    ...
]
```

Или полноценные классы.

Comment: В [Питон 3.7 словари упорядочены](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html).¶ +1 к namedtuple (для неизменяемых объектов подходит). Связанный вопрос [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495719/23044)