# Как создать экземпляр класса Car, используя в качестве атрибутов список b

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть список

```
b = ['car', 'Nissan xTtrail', '4', 'f1.jpeg', '2.5']
```

Определены классы:

```
class CarBase:
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying):
        self.car_type = car_type
        self.brand = brand
        self.photo_file_name = photo_file_name
        self.carrying = carrying`

class Car(CarBase):
    def __init__(self, car_type, brand, passenger_seats_count, 
               photo_file_name, carrying):
        super(Car, self).__init__(car_type, brand, photo_file_name, carrying)
        self.passenger_seats_count = passenger_seats_count`
```

Подскажите, как создать экземпляр класса Car, используя в качестве атрибутов как раз список `b`.

Т.е. если вызвать `x = Car(b)`, то интерпретатор будет ругаться на отсутствие обязательных аргументов `brand` и прочее.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594651

Comment: x = Car(*b), тогда работает как надо, если я правильно понял

Comment: рассмотрите возможность использования namedtuple или dataclass для `Car` или `b`. См. [Можно ли как-нибудь упростить инициализацию классов на Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/495719/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае, когда b = ['car', 'Nissan xTtrail', '4', 'f1.jpeg', '2.5'],
используйте **x = Car(*b)**

Возможно, вам будет удобно использовать словарь следующего вида:
b = {'car_type': 'car', 'brand': 'Nissan xTtrail', 'passenger_seats_count': '4', 'photo_file_name': 'f1.jpeg', 'carrying': '2.5'}
Тогда требуется создавать экземпляр класса так:
**x = Car(**b)**

P.S. В последнем случае порядок элементов неважен - при инициализации всё "ляжет" как надо. **(не путать с x = Car(*b) !)**